# GoogleDrive get token + refresh token why is it so complicated?

Tags: android

I've spent the last two days searching and researching this matter and I must admit I'm shocked implementing this in Android is so insanely complicated compared to iOS or Windows which I already done!!

I'm trying to obtain a token and a refresh token to send to my back end server so it can handle Drive API calls on the user's behalf and its simply a HUGE mess!

I tried to follow many different blogs, endless different ways from google's developers page, countless posts here and other places.
Nothing works.

Maybe some one here can help me... 
Here's my current situation:

First I use

```
String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
        Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 10001);
```

to pick an account or register a new google account.
Then, I'm using

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                        new JacksonFactory(),
                        clientId,
                        secret,
                        Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE)).setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force")
                        .build();
```

to generate a GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow object. With this I can get a GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest. But the response I get only has a token. There is no refresh token.

I already approved the consent dialog that appeared which to my understanding should also provide me with a refresh token afterwards.

What am I doing wrong? Or atleast, is there any where I can find a clear example on how to obtain a refresh token???

Comment: Have you checked out the android documentation for the new Drive api? https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth

Comment: Yes. Definitely. But, unless I'm dead wrong, this flow does not provide me with the tokens I need. It just enables me to use Drive API calls inside my app. Correct?

Comment: With this code you should just have to pass the credential to an instance of Google Drive Service, you shouldn't need the token.

credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                .setSelectedAccountName(googleUserName);

        driveService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .build();

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the help. The account name I provide here, can I get it using the AccountPicker and then pass it on to the credentials method? Also as I mentioned, our backend server requires these 2 tokens. Thats the way it is currently built. Will I be able to obtain them using the way you have described here? Thanks

Comment: Yea basically for getting the user name you can initialize the credential with an empty string or null, then call startActivityForResult(
                credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_CODE); That will display the android account picker. Then you can override onActivityResult and handle the response to set the username on the credential and do whatever else you want with it. 

Unfortunately I don't think you can get the refresh token from GoogleAccountCredential, but I'd check the javadoc to be sure. It does have a getToken method for getting the access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after digging further... I eventually came across this [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth#offlineAccess).
It basically explains that the token + refresh token are not the responsibility of the app/client, it is the responsibility of the backend server and what the client needs to provide to the backend server is only a temporary authorisation code which is easily obtained using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()`. The server will use that auth code to generate a token and a refresh token for future usage. This is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse).
I hope this might help some one who encounters this issue in the future.